# Kubernetes ConfigMap Update

Tags: python, rest, http, kubernetes

I'm working on a python script for update the configmaps programmatically.

Example script at shown as below.

```
import requests

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json"}
configData = {
"apiVersion": "v1",
"kind": "ConfigMap",
"data": {
    "test2.load": "testimtest"
},
"metadata": {
    "name": "nginx2"
}
}

r = requests.patch("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps/nginx2", json=configData)
```

The interesting side of this problem is that I have no problem with POST and GET methods but when I want to update kubernetes configmaps with PATCH method of HTTP I'm getting

```
 "reason":"UnsupportedMediaType" //STATUS_CODE 415
```

How I can handle this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a Kubernetes client library, instead of making the raw HTTP calls yourself. Then you don't need to figure out the low-level connection stuff, as the library will abstract that away for you.

I've been using [Pykube](https://github.com/kelproject/pykube), which provides a nice pythonic API, though it does appear to be abandoned now.

You can also use the official [client-python](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python), which is actively maintained. The library is a bit more clunky, as it's based on an autogenerated OpenAPI client, but it covers lots of use-cases like streaming results.

Comment: Thanks for advice but I my main problem is about pod and container design . ıN my case a pod mut access to the kubernetes cluster master node . So that I do not want to setup the kubectl inside of a pod .  I handled all problem with little header changing that  is the code :   https://gist.github.com/WoodProgrammer/a49b74271529fa3195caa355e0f20148

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to read a bit to figure out if in fact this HTTP verb is supported, maybe you're having a permissions issue?

Regardless, my suggestion to you is to use the verbose option of kubectl to figure out stuff like that.

For example, let's say I want to delete a pod, I would:

```
kubectl -v=9 delete pod myapp
```

The output (I cleaned up a bit) should contain the information you're looking for:

```
I1315 14:42:19.153664 30452 round_trippers.go:417]
   curl -k -v -XDELETE -H "Accept: application/json, */*"
   -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.8.5 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/cce11c6"
   https://<ip>:<port>/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/myapp
...
```

so now if I have all the details I need to construct the methods in python or whatever, hope that makes sense and/or helps, try it with the `patch` command.

Comment: I've upgraded the  service account and roles with rolebinding at kubernetes side and also changed the header of python code . Thanks for your advice :)) That is the code : https://gist.github.com/WoodProgrammer/a49b74271529fa3195caa355e0f20148